# Why isn't the ${\gamma}^5$ matrix called ${\gamma}^4$?

Tags: physics, terminology, quantum-field-theory

This is not really a physical question, but it relates to notation in QED.

The ${\gamma}^5$ matrix is defined as

$${\gamma}^5=i{\gamma}^0 {\gamma}^1{\gamma}^2{\gamma}^3$$

Wouldn't it be more logical to write ${\gamma}^5$ as ${\gamma}^4$?

Comment: Presumably because under Wick rotation to Euclidean signature, the $x^0$-coordinate is often called $x^4$.

Comment: @QMechanic According to QFT in a Nutshell your $x^4$ guess is correct.

Comment: [The number $5$ is a relic of old notation in which $\gamma ^{0}$ was called $\gamma ^{4}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#The_fifth_gamma_matrix.2C_.CE.B35)

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia;

> Although $\gamma ^{5}$ uses the letter gamma, it is not one of the gamma matrices of Cl1,3(R). The number 5 is a relic of old notation in which $\gamma ^{0}$ was called "$\gamma ^{4}$".